# Deserealización en Java de Python

Tags: java, python, socket, serialización

Quiero enviar desde Python un objeto hacia Java por sockets siendo Python(cliente) y Java(servidor), sin embargo no lo logro hacer y solo me aparece esto:

> invalid stream header: 8003635F

Lo intente con Python-Python y Java-Java, y no tuve ningún inconveniente.
Quisiera saber si mi codigo está mal o hay algo que estoy obviando. Estaré atento a cualquier respuesta. Gracias.
Adjunto Codigo:

**Código Java**
public class Test1 {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 10002;
        try {
            ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Esperando un cliente...");
            Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
            System.out.println("Conectado: " + cliente.getInetAddress());
            Vehiculo coche;
            ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
            coche = (Vehiculo) entrada.readObject();
            System.out.println("Marca: " + coche.getMarca() + "Modelo: " + coche.getModelo());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class Vehiculo implements Serializable {

    private String marca;
    private String modelo;

    public Vehiculo(String marca, String modelo) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehiculo{" + "marca=" + marca + ", modelo=" + modelo + '}';
    }
}
```

**Código Python**

```
class Vehiculo():
    def __init__(self,marca,modelo):
        self.marca = marca
        self.modelo = modelo
        
    def estado(self):
        print("Marca: ",self.marca,"\nModelo: ",self.modelo)

coche1 = Vehiculo("Mazda","3") 
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
serverAddress = ("172.16.4.18",10002) 
sock.connect(serverAddress)
sock.send(pickle.dumps(coche1)) 
sock.close()
```

Comment: La serialización binaria de objetos es dependientes de cada lenguaje de programación, es decir que no hay a la fecha(al menos que yo sepa) un estándar que sea implementado por todos los lenguajes de programación para la serialización binaria de objetos, es por eso que no existe ese concepto de cross binary serialization entre lenguajes. Existe una librería que nunca he probado pero que parece dar solución a tu problema **javaobj-py3**. Verifica que funcione para tu caso de uso o piensa en un método de serialización que no sea binaria, tal como a través de formatos JSON, XML, etc.

Comment: Lo revisaré gracias por la información